# What does a user see when their question is closed?

Tags: discussion, closing

I think it would be useful for those that have the privilege of casting close votes to know exactly what happens when a user has a question closed.

> What does a user see when their question is closed? Do they get a notification informing them that the question is closed?

Personally, answers to these questions could definitely affect my decisions regarding close votes in the future.

Comment: I'm tempted to close this question, so you could see for yourself! :-)

Comment: When I have had questions closed, I couldn't see anything through the tears.

Comment: Sounds of an immature boarding school chant from the corner: Asaf, Asaf, Asaf, Asaf, Asaf, Asaf, Asaf, ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Do they get a notification informing them that the question is closed?

At present, they do not (see [In which way the OP is notified about close votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222473/)). There is an old and popular feature request asking for this to be changed: [Send authors an inbox message if their question gets closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93842/).

*Usually* at least one comment is left before a question is closed, which serves as a kind of notification. When I review a question in the Close Queue and there are no comments yet, I usually post one.

Still, this isn't a satisfactory state of things. I don't   know what's stopping SE from sending a notification of similar style as for expired bounties. For what it's worth (which is nothing) I put a bounty on that feature request.

> What does a user see when their question is closed?

Almost the same thing you see. For *duplicates*, the language is a bit different: it mentions editing the post rather than asking a new question. And the banner on top of the question is visible to them sooner, after the first duplicate vote.

Comment: I believe that when closing for a duplicate the users sees a banner while closing in progress.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, that too.  I  had a couple of questions closed as a duplicate on Meta.

Answer (score 3):

No. I had a question closed and I didn't get a notification. Then my question was deleted. There wasn't even a comment.

Comment: Sorry. I don't like comment-less closures myself (having closed thousands of questions by now). The comment I usually add, with some variations, is "See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and advice on [asking good questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959)." I have a bookmarklet inserting it with one click...