# Are askers notified of close votes on a question they've asked?

Tags: discussion, support, closing, etiquette, notifications

If I encounter a question that is, for example, missing context, so I give it a close vote accordingly, is the poster notified? Or should I copy the relevant blurb:

> Please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

What are the norms here? How is a poster supposed to know that their question is not in accordance with the rules, so they can try to fix the problem?

Comment: Comments to the asker are certainly appreciated.  It may help them to curb the issue early on.

Comment: Proposals to copy and paste the blurb have met with some extraordinary hostility here on "meta". Why that has happened has mystified me.

Comment: There is a feature request to add the notification for *closures* (rather than just close votes): [Send authors an inbox message if their question is closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93842). It was marked (status-planned) back in March 2020, we'll see when there will be some further development. It was mentioned also in answers/comments here:
[What does a user see when their question is closed?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16385#16386), 
[Is there a notification of “on hold” and “closed”?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21660), ...

Comment: ... [Notifications to followers of a question about its status updates (closed / open)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32027).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, they are not notified. That is unless you vote to close as a duplicate, or use a custom off-topic reason; those actions generate a comment and they *are* notified of comments. Note that users need to have [250 reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes) to even *see* the close votes; other users do not notice them until their question is actually closed.

If you're reasonably sure the question will be closed in short notice, leaving a comment isn't really necessary, as it would essentially be duplicating the eventual notice. Rather than duplicating the notice, you could try to give some specific guidance for improving the question.

Comment: Personally, I would prefer duplicated notice on my posts than nothing at all. At least that would give some advanced warning to improve the question before it is closed. Specific guidance is of course preferred however.

Comment: @user400188 There is a [list of comment templates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4925/10513), which is a sort of middle ground between duplicating the notice and giving specific advice (you can of course write your own list of templates). Using templates can also be useful when giving specific guidance, as often the guidance is a variation on a theme, so write a template for that theme and then edit it as appropriate.